# Unable to export PATH from .zshrc

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I am trying to append the go lang path to my path variable. So far, I have been successful in doing this directly through the terminal with the following command:

```
export PATH=/path/to/go:$PATH
```

However when I add this line to my .zshrc, it does not seem to append to the variable. I have tried restarting the terminal, manually sourcing the .zshrc, and using this format for adding to the path:

```
path+=/path/to/go
export PATH
```

None of these have worked as expected. As mentioned before, when I do this through the terminal, it works fine, but I want this to be a persistent setting. Any help/input is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I put the line directly beneath the first commented section:

```html
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Do you know why this wouldn't work when the line was placed further down in the file?

Comment: You may find this article helpful.  https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux